# Odoo: set select item from many2many_tags widget

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have a button inside my customer refund form.When i click on it, i loop through all invoice lines to update the column "tax" to display the corresponding tax. I'm able to get the id of the associated tax (the tax column is a many2many_tags widget )for the product.
Now i want to display the item with that ID using python. Please any suggestions.

[image]

```
res['value']['invoice_line_tax_id']=mytaxeid doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [triplets](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/openerp/models.py#L3772) for many2many fields.

2 examples:

1. Replace all taxes with taxes IDs 2 and 4

```py
res['value']['invoice_line_tax_id'] = [(6, 0, [2, 4])]
```

2. Add the tax with ID 7

```py
res['value']['invoice_line_tax_id'] = [(4, 7)]
```